# Maximum volume of a cuboid with constraints

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find maximum volume of cuboid for which sum of three dimensions (x,y,z) is not greater then 108. 
I am looking for the most straightforward approach to the question.
Thus the volume will be $xyz$ and the sum of dimensions will be $x+y+z \le108$.
 For certain i have to calculate gradient, but what next?

Comment: Volume should be maximal for a cube, i.e. equal side lengths.

Comment: i am curios where does this guess come from?

Comment: Of course that's obvious, but I was going to let the O.P. discover that after diligently carrying out the approach I outlined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions, which come into play for constrained optimization, and are more complicated than classic use of Lagrange multipliers when there are inequality constraints.  In your problem, it is obvious that the constraint will be satisfied with equality at the optimum, otherwise you could increase one of the dimensions, while keeping the others fixed, and get a greater volume, so such a point couldn't be optimal. So you can replace the inequality constraint with an equality constraint x + y + z = 108.  Because of this, the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions reduce down to classic use of Lagrange multipliers to solve an equality constrained optimization problem.  Now you can apply (i.e., multiply) a Lagrange multiplier on the constraint, add it to the objective function x * y * z, and set the gradient of the whole thing with respect to x, y, and z equal to zero, and solve this together with x + y + z = 108. This will give you a critical point.   Technically, you still need to validate that any critical point is a maximum, but this should be obvious.

You also have implicit constraints that x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0.  If you don't pay attention to those, you could "cheat", by having, say, x and y be negative, still getting a positive volume, and making a farce out of the x + y + z <= 108 constraint.  In fact, you could achieve an infinite "volume". If you include these constraints, keep your x + y + z <= 108 as inequality, and solve the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions, you'll find that x = y = z = 0 is a solution satisfying the criteria to be a minimum, which it is.

You can look this up on Wikipedia, but I've given you a pretty good hint.